# How to put an image in the Thumbnail List Ionic with array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following Array. 
This is my `home.ts`

```
initializeItems() {
this.items = [
  {nome:'Abaeté', rua:'text' , 
   imagem:"assets/img/4Wj6RBrjQPGiTMhV6T9W_Abaete.JPG"}
 ];
}
```

And here I have the code `home.html` where is my ion-list

```
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-thumbnail item-left>
          <img src="assets/img/4Wj6RBrjQPGiTMhV6T9W_Abaete.JPG" />
        </ion-thumbnail>
        {{ item }}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

But on my ion-list the name and image are not going!
Here's an example image
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to do the "mapping" correctly here:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-thumbnail item-left>
      // use property binding like this, question mark in case the item is not available:
      <img [src]="item?.imagem"/>
    </ion-thumbnail>
    {{ item?.nome }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The way it work is that with ngFor directive you "iterate" over array like structures (array in your case):

```
[
  { // this will be "item", which properties you access using item.property
    nome:'Abaeté', 
    rua:'text', 
    imagem:"assets/img/4Wj6RBrjQPGiTMhV6T9W_Abaete.JPG"
  }
]
```

Comment: Very good, but when I search the name of the building appears the following message: item.tolowercase is not a function

Comment: Hey Mike, this is why you need to post full code of yours. Its impossible to help you unless you share full implementation.

Comment: Ideally use https://stackblitz.com/ to post your code snippet - this way you can get help real fast. I guess you are coding simple search filter. I would reco read this guide here: https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/